# Qt, how to emit signal to parent widget?

Tags: python, qt5, pyside, qitemdelegate

Hi i have created a widget to use it in `QTableWidget`

this Widget is a simple `QComboBox`

```
class ComboDelegate(QtGui.QItemDelegate):
    """
    A delegate that places a fully functioning QComboBox in every
    cell of the column to which it's applied
    """
    def __init__(self, parent, options):

        QtGui.QItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)
        self.options = options
        self.parent = parent

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        combo = QtGui.QComboBox(parent)
        combo.addItems(self.options)
        self.connect(combo, QtCore.SIGNAL("currentIndexChanged(int)"), self, QtCore.SLOT("currentIndexChanged()"))
        return combo

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        editor.blockSignals(True)
        editor.setCurrentIndex(editor.currentIndex())
        editor.blockSignals(False)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        self.parent.item(self.parent.currentRow(), 4).setText("%s Byte" % editor.currentIndex())
        model.setData(index, editor.itemText(editor.currentIndex()))

    #@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def currentIndexChanged(self):
        pass
        self.commitData.emit(self.sender())
```

When a user change the Value of `ComboDelegate`, that Widget update a value of another cell, this cell is the `Size cell`

```
self.parent.item(self.parent.currentRow(), 4).setText("%s Byte" % editor.currentIndex() # Size cell
```

in my `MainWindow` class i have assigned a slot when a cell is changed

```
self.Table.cellChanged.connect(lambda: self.change_xml_entry(self.Table))
```

`change_xml_entry` should update the xml entry when a cell is updated! it works fine when the cell updated directly manually from the user, but when my `ComboDelegate` class update the `Size cell`, the parent Widget `self.Table` doesn't receive a signal to know that the cell has been changed so it doesn't update the xml entry

Comment: Is the signal emited? Just connect to a small method printing a short text.